# How to zoom an image when we touch it and zoom out when touch releases android

Tags: android, dialog, imageview, zooming

I am working on an android application and want to same effect on popup images as Facebook shows on reactions icons when we click on Like button in feeds.
Please check the below image.
[image]

I am using Dialog box and Recyclerview inside it to show these images. These images are being shown using ImageView in recyclerview. Now I want to apply such a effect that whenever I touch any image of recyclerview, it should show the view like above image (Zoom + description of that image).
How can I apply this effect on images.

Please provide me an idea about this, so that I can proceed further.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: let's put these bigger images in advanced there and make them hide .when the use will click the particular image it will show.try it once.

Comment: @Sushrita: Thanks a lot for your reply. But As the above images shows I want to show these images half in dialog box and half outside the dialog box, for which I think I need to do something else, can you please give me a solution for this. Thanks a lot in advanced.